# Force close when trying to use BetterAsyncTask in droid-fu Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, droid-fu

I am currently trying to use the android library android fu to help me with my first proper app.

I am trying to makea test project using the droid fu library but when ever i go to test the app it force closes.

I have used an example of the asynctask and when i test the app it loads and does what its meant to but when i replace it with the betterasynctask the app force closes.

You can download the source of the test app from http://androidapp.dino-digital.com/DroidFuTest.zip

Comment: Can you show the stack trace? In eclipse look at the logcat window, or run adb logcat from the command line.

Comment: Hi this is the what i get when i debug the app in eclipse (logcat window)

http://androidapp.dino-digital.com/logcat.txt

Comment: Are you using BetterActivity? They're meant to be used together

Comment: Hi i am using the BetterDefaultActivity. I have done what hwrdprkns said and the example now works without a dialog. 

I would ideally like to have the progress dialog loading while doing something in the background like downloading xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though hwrdprkns was correct as to disabling the dialog will make the app work to be able to get the progress dialog to work i add to the following to get the dialog to work.

Call both lines to set the dialog content

```
super.setProgressDialogTitleId(R.string.dialog_title);
super.setProgressDialogMsgId(R.string.dialog_message);
```

OR

define `"droidfu_progress_dialog_title"` and `droidfu_progress_dialog_message` in your strings.xml

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by you not providing a valid resource pointer for your dialog. Right after you instantiate the task -- try calling the `task.disableDialog();` method. It should work after that.

EDIT: Seeing as the user wants a custom dialog -- I'd point you to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) link. Just create a new custom dialog(or just use the Android's helper methods for creating a dialog) and reference that ID from your code.

Comment: thanks that worked for that example but what would i do if i wanted the progressDialog while its doing an action like downloading an xml file in the background?